# How do you search an inbox using the EWS Managed API with ColdFusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are using ColdFusion 2016 and are using the EWS API to connect to exchange.  I have managed to get the code sample from the following post working but am not able to figure out how to use the SearchFilter with the findItems() method.
[Why is the get action of cfexchangemail never returning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048664/why-is-the-get-action-of-cfexchangemail-never-returning?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
service = createObject("Java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService");
service.init();

version = createObject("Java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion");
service.init(version.Exchange2010);

credentials = createObject("Java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials");

credentials.init(yourusername, yourpassword);
service.setCredentials(credentials);

uri = createObject("Java", "java.net.URI");
uri.init("outlook webservices url");
service.setUrl(uri);
WellKnownFolderName=createObject("Java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName");
result = service.FindItems(service.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, CreateObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemView").init(100));

for(item in result.getItems(){
    // ..loop through each field and store their value 
    // in query object or something...
}
```

So basically is it possible to translate this Java code to Coldfusion?

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults =
    service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
        new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
            LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "EWS"),
        new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "API")), view);

service.loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

for (Item item : findResults) {
    System.out.println(item.getSubject());
    System.out.println(item.getBody());
    // Do something with the item.
}
```

**Update from comments:**

I can't figure out how to instantiate the `SearchFilter` or `SearchFilterCollection`. I tried creating a searchFilter object, but it does not have the properties to work with. I must be must be missing something.

```
CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Sea‌​rchFilter");
```

Comment: (Edit) What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I can't figure out how to instantiate the searchFilter or SearchFilterCollection.  `code`SearchFilter.new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
            LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "EWS"))`code`.  When creating this searchFilter object it does not have the properties to work with. I must be must be missing something.
 CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not an a full answer, but too long for comments)

No wonder... that is a *lot* of nesting. I do not have that lib installed, but if it were me I would start by breaking it down into separate statements, one `new` object per line. Start with the innermost constructor:

```
new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(
          ItemSchema.Subject
        , "API"
    )
```

You will need to create an instance of `ItemSchema` first, to have access the `Subject` property. Looking at the [C# docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema_members(v=exchg.80).aspx) (no javadocs available) the path should be something like this:

```
ItemSchema = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemSchema");
```

After that move on to creating the `SearchFilter`. Notice the period `.` in the class name? The keyword `new` followed by a class name, containing a period, usually means it is an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Inner classes require a special syntax, ie `ParentClass$InnerClass`. Something like this should work:

```
APISubString = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter$ContainsSubstring");
writeDump(APISubString );
```

If it works, add `init()` to initialize the object:

```
  APISubString = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring").init(ItemSchema.Subject, "API");
```

Then move to the next innermost object:

```
new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(
           ItemSchema.Subject
          , "EWS"
    )
```

and lather, rinse, repeat for the remaining objects:

```
// ItemSchema.Subject is a static value and can be reused
EWSSubString = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring").init(ItemSchema.Subject, "EWS");
```

Comment: The syntax to call the the InnerClass was my missing link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The final working result was:

```
folderName = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName");
itemView = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemView").init(10,0);
folderID = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.FolderId").init(
        folderName.Inbox,
        mailBox
        );
sortDirection = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SortDirection");
basePropertySet = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.BasePropertySet");
propertyset = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertySet");
itemSchema = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemSchema");
searchFilterCollection = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter$SearchFilterCollection");
logicalOperator = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.LogicalOperator");
subString1 = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter$ContainsSubstring").init(
        itemSchema.Subject,
        "EWS"
        );
subString2 = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SearchFilter$ContainsSubstring").init(
        itemSchema.Subject,
        "API"
        );
searchFilterCollection.add(SubString1);
searchFilterCollection.add(SubString2);
searchFilterCollection.setLogicalOperator(LogicalOperator.Or);
bodyType = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.BodyType");
propertyset.add(itemSchema.Subject);
propertyset.add(itemSchema.DateTimeReceived);
propertyset.setBasePropertySet(basePropertySet.IdOnly);
propertyset.setRequestedBodyType(bodyType.HTML);
itemView.getOrderBy().add(itemSchema.DateTimeReceived, sortDirection.Ascending);
itemView.setPropertySet(propertyset);
viewResults = service.findItems(folderID, searchFilterCollection, itemView);
```